# The specified invariant name 'System.Data.OleDb' wasn't found in the list of registered .NET Data Providers

Tags: .net, .net-core

В приложении ловлю ошибку:

> The specified invariant name 'System.Data.OleDb' wasn't found in the
>   list of registered .NET Data Providers.

Если собирать консольное приложение под .Net Core 3.0.

Если я собираю под 4,7, то все норм.

В чем может быть проблема?

Пытаюсь воспользоваться провайдером  `Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0`

P.S Если информации мало, то могу еще накидать. Только скажите что нужно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем, если добавить вот такую строчку:

```
 DbProviderFactories.RegisterFactory("System.Data.OleDb", OleDbFactory.Instance);
```

То все начинает работать.

На вопрос: почему так стало? Я пришёл к выводу, что из-за концепции модульности и кроссплатформенности. Теперь oledb и sqlserver ставятся из nuget => проинициализировать все заранее нельзя, как это было в классическом фреймворка, когда все лежало рядом. Теоретически, конечно майки могли если бы через рефлексия изучили бы загруженные сборки и т д, но это заняло бы лишнее время, так как подобная концепция используется во многих местах теперь. Например, если нужны какие-то доп кодировки, то нужно ставить отдельную сборку и регистрировать провайдер.

Вот [этот](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52039785/4244707) ответ помог.

Comment: @Drakonoved, Здесь уже указано самое главное. Это не ответ-ссылка, это ответ где дана ссылка на ассоциативный ответ на enSO. Конечно, неплохо было увидеть не много объяснений, но может быть автор не очень хорошо владеет  мат.частью, и не готов дать их.

Comment: Ну я,, вроде, дополнил свой ответ.